# How did the editor get around the six-character limit?

Tags: support, editing

I'm looking at revision number two [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/85712/revisions).

The editor said "previous suggested edit rejected: please do not add padding to get around the 6 char limit".

However, when I load the side-by-side markdown of @Aurora0001's edit, I only see that two characters have changed.

From this example, I'm not seeing an obvious solution to the case where a single unicode dash has to be corrected in a code block, and the system rejects my edit because it does not change 6 characters.

Obviously I'm glad that a "non-padded" version of my edit was able to be implemented, but I would like to know how I should have proceeded in this case, especially given the normative wording of the corrected edit message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That six character limit doesn't apply to everyone.  I don't where, if anywhere, it is formally documented, as the [help center pages on privileges](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) actually aren't exhaustive.  It would make sense that it would be at the same point as you are allowed to do edits without approval: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit (which Aurora is).

There is some explanation/justification of the limit on Meta proper: 
[Why should edits be at least six non-space characters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140288/212479)

Interestingly, the one answer there, from ~6.5 years ago, does refer to shimming stuff in if you have to.